# Install php rasbian stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, php

I would install php (php-fpm) on my raspberry pi 3 b+.
Its running with raspbian stretch 9 i dont have choice, i must keep this version.
I can’t even update, the official mirrors that are programmed to be used no longer work on Stretch and earlier.

How Can i install it with a USB key?

I dont know if its Can help but nginx is installed.
I want php because i need to execute a script to shutdown the raspberry from an interface (which is a HTML page, that i Can access from my phone connected from wifi raspberry).
Ive tried flask but i cant install it with pip.

Thanks for reading and excuse my english

Comment: Why can’t you change from Stretch?

Comment: Because the IMG ive downloaded is build with Stretch, the author doesnt have the time to update it and i dont have the skills to do it myself :( its an old img

Comment: What is this img?

Comment: A live lightpainting application https://oliver-mayer.com/work_f1uxu5.html and github https://github.com/0may/f1uxu5

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments; EDIT your Question.

Answer (score 0):

The old raspbian have been moved to legacy (Stretch on 17-Aug-2023) but haven't been updated for years (and never will).
The old mirrors no longer exist.

Try `deb http://legacy.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

---

This should work but custom OS may differ.

Frankly custom OS are a bad idea - if the author of a program doesn't offer a version installable on a standard OS (preferably with source) I would give it a miss.